# Conexion a Postgres des php

Tags: php, postgresql

Tengo un problema al realizar mi conexión de **php** con **postgres**.
Al verificar la conexión me aparece este error:

> Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server:
> authentication method 10 not supported in

Ya realicé cambios en el `pg_hba`, cambie de Scram a MD5, y cambié la encryption a MD5, pero aún así me sigue apareciendo este error

Si alguien me puede ayudar, ya no se que solución intentar

Este es el código que tengo en mi php

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "postgres";
$pass = "admin";
$bd = "dev";
$port = "5432";

$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$bd user=$user password=$pass") or die ("Error al conectar con el Servidor:");
```

Comment: ¿Versión de Postgres y PHP?

Comment: debido al trabajo me pidieron usar php 5.6.40 y postgres 16

Comment: La información que hay en la red no es muy clara, pero todo apunta a que PHP 5 no soporta Postgres > 10. La raíz de todo fue un [cambio en la autenticación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64476213/1545868) que se dio en Postgres 10 y afecta las versiones siguientes. Posiblemente tengas que usar un PHP actualizado. Otras opciones: tratar de conectar por [ODBC](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/) o intentar hacer una API REST en un PHP nuevo (u otra tecnología) y que el PHP antiguo la consuma.

Comment: Fijate que ya logré ver cuál era el problema, y si como dices PHP 5 no soporta Postgres > 10, pero hay una forma para poder conectar, ya que lo que no es muy compatible son los métodos de encriptación. PHP 5 parece que no soporta MD5 ni SCRAM, por lo cuál lo cambié y lo dejé con PASSWORD, lo cuál si permite Postgres, y ya con eso me dejo conectar con la base de datos, aunque no es muy seguro, pero sigo investigando si hay manera de habilitar el MD5 o SCRAM en esa versión de PHP, pero por el momento debido al trabajo debo trabajar con esas versiones

Answer (score 1):

debes usar obligatoriamente pg_ para hacer las consultas en postgreSQL? Porque puedes usar PDO para establecer la conexión y consulta a posgreSQL. En mi parte me gusta mas trabajar con PDO que con su pg_ o mysqli_. Aquí un ejemplo del código de conexión

```
$contraseña = "hunter2";
$usuario = "parzibyte";
$nombreBaseDeDatos = "mascotas";
# Puede ser 127.0.0.1 o el nombre de tu equipo; o la IP de un servidor remoto
$rutaServidor = "127.0.0.1";
$puerto = "5432";
try {
    $base_de_datos = new PDO("pgsql:host=$rutaServidor;port=$puerto;dbname=$nombreBaseDeDatos", $usuario, $contraseña);
    $base_de_datos->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Ocurrió un error con la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

si quieres saber más te dejo este enlace de un blog. https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/06/17/conectar-postgresql-php-pdo-crud/